# Formalizing volume over rationals

Tags: measure-theory

It is a remarkable result of measure theory that there is no function on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is countably additive on disjoint sets, translation invariant, and outputs $(\text{length} \times \text{width} \times \text{height})$ for boxes. Does this result also hold for subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^3$?

Comment: I mean, it's a countable set...

Comment: I'm not sure how being countable implies the existence or nonexistence of such a function. countable sets are Lebesgue measure 0 if the interval coverings are intervals of real numbers. But we could consider rational coverings or completely different set functions

Comment: No, the same things hold for the rationals as well. That is not hard to see. Just check.

Comment: The Lebsegue out measure restricted to rational interval coverings of countable sets would still be 0. I see that now. So if we tried to extend lebesgue outer measure this way, every set would be measure 0. Does this imply the nonexistence of such a function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what this means.

Comment: I think I almost get it. Could you please maybe write one or two more details about how we could conclude that?

Comment: Translation invariant means every singleton has the same measure, and the requirements about interval length mean that intervals should have a positive and finite measure. But if the interval is countable, then the measure is either 0 (if each point is null) or infinite (otherwise). So there cannot be such a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111866/discussion-between-david-warren-katz-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Sorry, no can do at the moment.